# trigonometry equation - $\sin^3(x)+\sin^3(2x)+\sin^3(3x) = (\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x))^3$

Tags: trigonometry

how can i find all possible solutions to this equation?

$\sin^3(x)+\sin^3(2x)+\sin^3(3x) = (\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x))^3$

I've tried writing it all as a sum in the form $\sin^m(x)\cos^n(x) + ... sin(x)$, with just $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ occuring. For my luck, you can write it in the form $\sin(x)* (...) = 0$ and therefore you can find a few solutions. But inside the brackets there is an expression starting with somthing like $\sin^7(x)$ which i cant handle and dont find any other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sin x=a$, $\sin2x=b$,
and $\sin3x=c$

Expand out

$(a+b+c)^3$

Then subtract $a^3, b^3$ and $c^3$, which yields

$3 a^2 b + 3 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 6 a b c + 3 a c^2 + 3 b^2 c + 3 b c^2=0$.

The long expression can be factored nicely into :

$3(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$, which equal  to $0$.

The factor $3$ makes no difference, so solve for:

$\sin(x)+\sin(2x)=0$,

$\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)=0$, and

$\sin(x)+\sin(3x)=0$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

HINT: expanding and factorizing your equation we get
$$-3\, \left( \sin \left( 2\,x \right) +\sin \left( 3\,x \right) 
 \right)  \left( \sin \left( x \right) +\sin \left( 3\,x \right) 
 \right)  \left( \sin \left( x \right) +\sin \left( 2\,x \right) 
 \right)
=0$$
can you finish this?